# How to configure the regex in scalstyleCheck for header check?

Tags: regex, scala, scalastyle

Suppose I want to check that my every scala file has a header similar to

```
/*
 *  Copyright (c) 2020-2021 XYZ company ltd
 *  All Rights Reserved.
*/
```

Now the scalastyle_config.xml has an entry like

```
<check enabled="true" class="org.scalastyle.file.HeaderMatchesChecker" level="warning">
   <parameters>
   <parameter name="regex">true</parameter>
   <parameter name="header">Copyright (c) 2020-2021 XYZ company ltd</parameter>
   </parameters>
</check>
```

What should be the regex to match the header content I pasted above?

I tried specifying the parameter as

```
<parameter name="header">Copyright \(c\) (?:\d{4}-)?\d{4} XYZ company ltd</parameter>
```

but even that doesn't match my header and it fails the headerCheck.

Comment: The pattern matches https://regex101.com/r/Me5Wip/1 How did you implement the regex?

Comment: I am using the plugin `com.github.alisiikh:gradle-scalastyle-plugin_2.12:2.1.0` which handles that part. I am having difficulty writing the regex

Comment: Did you try double escaping the backslashes?